# Engrampa segmentation fault error in 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I've just installed Engrampa 1.26.0 but when I try to unzip or untar an archive the application crashes with the message:

```
segmentation fault (core dumped).
```

Is there any fix or possibility to install a latest version ?

Comment: How did you install it? Look at the `/var/crash/*grampa*`. The files in `/var/crash` are simple text files, use `less` to read them.

Comment: `segmentation fault` is Linux's way of saying "illegal memory reference", as a reference to location 0, or an other out-of-bounds address. Is `Engrampa` crashing? Do: `ldd $(type -p engrampa)`. Are you missing a shared library? Is the archive corrupt?

Comment: @waltinator Yes Engrampa is crashing, it's a memory leak problem. There is a new release (1.26.1) that fixes this issue on Github [link](https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/releases/tag/v1.26.1)  but I don't know how to install it.